# How do I link GLFW

Tags: c, opengl, glfw

I am trying to link GLFW to my C program.

The docs seem to suggest `#include<GLFW/glfw3.h>` however I have installed 2.7.2 (from my distro's repository) and don't have that header file:

```
find / -name *glfw* 2> /dev/null
/usr/lib/libglfw.so.2.6
/usr/lib/libglfw.a
/usr/lib/libglfw.so
/usr/lib/pkgconfig/libglfw.pc
/usr/lib/libglfw.so.2
/usr/include/GL/glfw.h
/usr/share/doc/libglfw-dev
/usr/share/doc/libglfw2
/var/cache/apt/archives/libglfw2_2.7.2-1_i386.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/libglfw-dev_2.7.2-1_i386.deb
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libglfw2.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libglfw2.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libglfw-dev.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libglfw2.postrm
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libglfw2.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libglfw2.shlibs
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libglfw-dev.list
```

I tried `#include<GL/glfw.h>` but I still get `undefined reference to 'glfwLoadTexture2D'`

How do I link to GLFW and use `glfwLoadTexture2D()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `#include` does nothing for the linker; it just brings in *declarations*, not the actual functions.

[The documentation](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/build.html) indicates that GLFW uses [pkg-config](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/pkg-config/) (not surprising; [@elmindreda](https://stackoverflow.com/users/142275/elmindreda) knows her stuff), so your compilation line should be something like:

```
$ cc `pkg-config --cflags glfw3` -o foo foo.c `pkg-config --static --libs glfw3`
```

Also note that since the library uses `pkg-config`, you're not supposed to "care" about details such as where the header and library files are located on your particular installation. Just ask using the `--cflags` and `--libs` modes, and you will get the proper locations returned, as the example above indicates.

Comment: Okay I am obviously missing something basic, because I assumed that as I found the headers in `GL/glfw.h`, that `-lGL` would be enough to link to it :/

Comment: @trideceth12 The `-l` command-line option links exactly one library, if you say `GL` it will link with `libGL.so`, not "all libraries under some folder somewhere called `GL`". Read up on the compiler documentation too.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing up compilation and linking. If you were missing headers, you would probably have errors a lot sooner than the linking stage.

"Undefined reference" results from symbols not being found by the linker. The most likely cause is you not telling `gcc` that it should link to the GLFW libraries:

```
 gcc myfile.c -lglfw
```

Answer (score 1):

When I am on Linux, I compile opengl/glfw projects like this:

```
gcc main.c -lGL -lglfw
```

When I am on windows, I compile them by writing:

```
gcc main.c libglfw3.a -lopengl32 -lgdi32
```

and I put libglfw3.a file in the same directory where main.c is. I have read people say that they couldn't link properly before writing
`-lopengl32 -lgdi32 -luser32 -lkernel32 -lws2_32`.
Another thing which may be worth mentioning is that I couldn't link glfw libraries when I downloaded 32bit glfw binaries. When I downloaded 64bit glfw binaries everything worked fine. I have a 64 bit machine and a x86_64-w64-mingw32. I have read comments from people with the opposite experience, where they weren't able to link glfw libraries when they downloaded 64bit binaries, but they were able to link them after downloading 32bit binaries. My advice would be to try both.